# Linphone Compiling - configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs

Tags: c++, c, mingw, linphone

I am trying to compile Linphone for windows but when I run 
"./configure --prefix=/opt/linphone --enable-shared --disable-static"
I get an error message claiming that I cannot run C compiled programs.

I am using Mingw on Windows 8, I have installed the C++ and C compilers and also the Mingw Developer Tools

Comment: Well, did you try compiling "HelloWorld.c" and running it?

Comment: You may also want to follow the instructions on here: http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/guide/compiling.html

Comment: @mats-petersson This is what I have attempted, however it is not working for me due to the error above.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It appears to be a target mismatch error. Mingw32 binaries cannot be run on windows 32-bit kernel. You should try installing Mingw64 binaries. Also try building from a linux or windows machine. I had this issue which I resolved later by compiling on Mac.

Comment: Really? All normal Windows apps work as 32-bit on 64-bit OS - including older versions of MingW - as I have used that combination myself.

Comment: @varun I cannot seem to find a 64 bit Mingw binary, any ideas where I can get one?

Comment: ming64 is already present. try setting --target flag in the configure script. Also set --build=i586-mingw32